# C# and database visual 2012

Tags: c#, database

THe problem is when i add the user(any information) occurs the following error. But I already set up everything with database.
_>>>>"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;        //for DB connection

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class DataBaseConnect
{
    string result;
    //method that establish a connection to database
    private static OleDbConnection GetDBConnection()
    {
        string connString;
        //  change to your connection string in the following line
        connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source=C:C:\Users\user\Desktop\SAAD Assignment1\IOOP Assignment\Library.accdb";
        return new OleDbConnection(connString);
    }


    public static List<Nurse> LoadNurseDetails()
    {
        List<Nurse> nurse = new List<Nurse>();
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Nurse";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                Nurse g = new Nurse(int.Parse(myReader["ID"].ToString()),  

 myReader["nurseName"].ToString(), int.Parse(myReader["rank"].ToString()));
                nurse.Add(g);
            }
            return nurse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }


    // Method that returns a list of normal patienr objects with the details from the DB
    public static List<NormalPatient> LoadNormalPatient()
    {
        List<NormalPatient> normal = new List<NormalPatient>();
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM normalPatient";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                NormalPatient g = new 
 NormalPatient(int.Parse(myReader["ID"].ToString()),    
 myReader["patientName"].ToString());
                normal.Add(g);
            }
            return normal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }


    private static Nurse FindNurse(List<Nurse> nurseList, int id)
    {
        foreach (var n in nurseList)
        {
            if (n.NurseId == id)
            {
                return n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static List<String> FindNurseByID(int nId)
    {
        List<String> nurseDetail = new List<String>();

        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Nurse WHERE ID =" + nId;

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery,
            myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                nurseDetail.Add(myReader["nurseName"].ToString() + "; Ranking:" + 
 myReader["rank"].ToString());
            }
            return nurseDetail;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execption in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

    private static NormalPatient FindPatient(List<NormalPatient> patientList, int id)
    {
        foreach (var p in patientList)
        {
            if (p.PatientID == id)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public string loginCheck(string user, string pass)
    {

        string checkdbuser;
        List<String> nurseDetail = new List<String>();

        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName and Password =" + user;

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery,myConnection);
        checkdbuser = "SELECT * FROM normalPatient";

            if (user == checkdbuser)
            {

                result = "true";

            }

        else
            {
                result = "false";

            }


            return result;
    }

    // find normal patient by ID
    public static List<String> FindNormalPatientByID(int pId)
    {
        List<String> patientDetail = new List<String>();

        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM normalPatient WHERE ID =" + pId;

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                patientDetail.Add(myReader["ID"].ToString() + "; Patient Name:" + 
 myReader["patientName"].ToString());
            }
            return patientDetail;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execption in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }




    //save to ward
    //method that saves noramal patient to ward
    public static void SaveWard(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, int n1, int n2)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO NormalWard (patient1, patient2, patient3, 
 patient4, patient5, nurse1, nurse2, DateAdmit) VALUES (" + p1 + ", " + p2 + ", " + p3 +              
 ", " + p4 + ", " + p5 + ", " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", '" + DateTime.Now.Date + "')";

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

    }





    public static List<CriticalNurse> LoadCriticalNurseDetails()
    {
        List<CriticalNurse> nurse = new List<CriticalNurse>();
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Critical_Nurse";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                CriticalNurse g = new 
CriticalNurse(int.Parse(myReader["ID"].ToString()), myReader["nurseName"].ToString(), 
int.Parse(myReader["rank"].ToString()));
                nurse.Add(g);
            }
            return nurse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }


    // Method that returns a list of critical patient objects with the details from the 
 DB
    public static List<CriticalPatient> LoadCriticalPatient()
    {
        List<CriticalPatient> normal = new List<CriticalPatient>();
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Critical_Patient";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                CriticalPatient g = new 
CriticalPatient(int.Parse(myReader["ID"].ToString()), 
 myReader["patientName"].ToString());
                normal.Add(g);
            }
            return normal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

    private static CriticalNurse FindCriticalNurse(List<CriticalNurse> nurseList, int 
 id)
    {
        foreach (var n in nurseList)
        {
            if (n.NurseId == id)
            {
                return n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }





    private static CriticalPatient FindCriticalPatient(List<CriticalPatient> 
  patientList, int id)
    {
        foreach (var p in patientList)
        {
            if (p.PatientID == id)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    // find critical patient by ID
    public static List<String> FindCriticalPatientByID(int pId)
    {
        List<String> patientDetail = new List<String>();

        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();

        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Critical_Patient WHERE ID =" + pId;

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                patientDetail.Add(myReader["ID"].ToString() + "; Patient Name:" + 
   myReader["patientName"].ToString());
            }
            return patientDetail;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execption in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

 public static void SaveNormalPatient(String name)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO normalPatient(patientName) VALUES ( '" + name + 
 "')";

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

    }

 public static void SaveCriticalPatient(String name)
 {
     OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();
     string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Critical_Patient(patientName) VALUES ( '" + name +                  
 "')";

     OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

     try
     {
         myConnection.Open();
         myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
     }
     finally
     {
         myConnection.Close();
     }

 }

 public static void SaveNormalNurse(String name, int rank)
 {
     OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();
     string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Nurse(nurseName, rank) VALUES ( '" + name + "', "+ 
rank+")";

     OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

     try
     {
         myConnection.Open();
         myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
     }
     finally
     {
         myConnection.Close();
     }

 }

 public static void SaveCriticalNurse(String name, int rank)
 {
     OleDbConnection myConnection = GetDBConnection();
     string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Critical_Nurse(nurseName, rank) VALUES ( '" + name + 
 "', " + rank + ")";

     OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

     try
     {
         myConnection.Open();
         myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
     }
     finally
     {
         myConnection.Close();
     }

   }

}

  }
```

Comment: Please see, [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"

Comment: did your connection string really mean to have 'C:C:'

Answer (score 0):

I searched the error message text "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" on "Google" and selected the first link.....

[MSDN - The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)